# In C++, how to write full implementation in header for classes and functions (possibly templated)

Tags: c++, header-files

I usually declare in header file and implement in cpp file, but now I am doing an assignment, and, apparently for brevity, the instructor doesn't want me to do that, but insists that I write all the code in header files.

So, what is the best way to do that?

For classes, should I declare everything first, and then go to the bottom of the page and start implementing?

```
class myClass 
{
void myMethod();
}

void myClass::myMethod() { //.... }
```

or should I just implement as I declare

```
class myClass 
{
void myMethod() { //... } ;
}
```

What about free functions?

And when should I write "inline"?

Comment: I typically implement class methods in class. `inline` required when writing out of class definitions and free functions.

Comment: *'I usually declare in header file and implement in cpp file'* - and that's the way you *normally* should do it. Sure, if instructor insists... Just return to what is good practice *afterwards* (suppose you are about to anyway, just wanted to be explicit about).

Comment: the "possibly templated" in your title suggests that your instructor told you to put everything in the header for a good reason: templates can only be implemented in header files

Answer (score 6):

> or should I just implement as I declare

Yes, implement them in class, not out of class. When the (questionable) reasoning of your instructor for putting everything into a header refers to brevity, this is obviously the way to go.

> What about free functions?

Same as with member functions, define them on the go.

> And when should I write "inline"?

You should add `inline` to all ordinary free functions. It's unnecessary for function templates or in-class member function definitions. When you can use C++17, consider inline variables, too.